# Where to close Close cursor and database object in Activity without any exception

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

In my application there are lot of database operations, so I have created many cursors to retrieve the data and there are few cursors used in Async Task as well. Now my issue is where to close the cursor and database.

When I closed the cursors in `onCreate` after the Async operation I am getting `Null Pointer Exception`, also if I close in `onPause` still I am getting `Null pointer exception`, so I have closed the cursor and database in `onDestroy`.

Now I am confused whether this approach is correct or not.. and I want to learn what is the best way to close a cursor and database in an activity without any effect on database operations.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockdetail);
        //Helptext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Declerations();

        d=Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();



        new popdailydata().execute();
// Above is async task so I have closed after above statement, but if I close cursor getting Null pointer exception

protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    selectdate.close();
    Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).close();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        //selectdate.close(); --- At this point also I am getting nullpointer exception
        Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).close();
    }
```

---

```
04-01 17:03:48.045: D/dalvikvm(1288): Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-01 17:03:50.021: D/libEGL(1288): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
04-01 17:03:50.113: D/(1288): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb90bb5c8, tid 1288
04-01 17:03:50.177: D/libEGL(1288): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
04-01 17:03:50.181: D/libEGL(1288): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
04-01 17:03:50.773: W/EGL_genymotion(1288): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-01 17:03:50.797: E/OpenGLRenderer(1288): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-01 17:03:50.861: E/OpenGLRenderer(1288): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-01 17:03:50.865: D/OpenGLRenderer(1288): Enabling debug mode 0
04-01 17:03:54.645: D/dalvikvm(1288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 102K, 1% free 16948K/17072K, paused 89ms, total 96ms
04-01 17:03:54.709: D/AndroidRuntime(1288): Shutting down VM
04-01 17:03:54.725: W/dalvikvm(1288): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c45648)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.portfoliomanager/com.example.StockDirector.stockmanager}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at com.example.StockDirector.stockmanager.onCreate(stockmanager.java:81)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-01 17:03:54.745: E/AndroidRuntime(1288):     ... 11 more
04-01 17:03:57.889: I/Process(1288): Sending signal. PID: 1288 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You haven't shown what you use your `Cursor` for or shown logcat output which shows the NPE. A `Cursor` MUST remain open for the lifetime of whatever app component needs it. For example, if you use it with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to populate a `ListView` you cannot close the `Cursor` until the `ListView` and `SimpleCursorAdapter` are no longer in use.

Comment: @Squonk Thanks for your answer and apologize for not providing the logcat... Edited my question with logcat. Please advice

Comment: That still doesn't really explain how you use the `Cursor`. You show that you're calling an `AsyncTask` but not what the `AsyncTask` does with the data retrieved.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@g2o: Please remember that: [**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) So instead of just replace `cusor` with `cursor`, *fix every issues* like what I did.

Answer (score 1):

For overall operations on android database manipulation, here is a great source of info for using content provider:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

And here is an example of how to implement a LoaderManager. You can find various examples here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

For a basic implementation idea, this is how it should look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            ObjectEntity.URI,   // Database uri
            new String[]{"id"}, // Columns to select
            "id=?",               // 'where' field
            new String[]{"3"},  // Values for 'where' '?' field
            null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Do anything you want here with the cursor
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your response... will go through the links.

Answer (score 0):

You should close at Database/Cursor connection as soon as possible, meaning once you pull the data from it you should close everything so that you do not lock the database.

holding onto database connections is bad practice especially for multi-threaded applications

Comment: Thanks for your response but that is my issue when I close immediately after any db operation it is throwing me `Null Pointer Exception`. In my question if I close after `new popdailydata().execute();` it is giving me the exception

Comment: @tyczj : Your answer isn't entirely correct. A `Cursor` must remain open if it's going to be used with an `Adapter` and `AdapterView`. Also, if you use a `SQLiteOpenHelper` then explicitly closing the database can be detrimental - check the source code.

Comment: @Siva if you are getting null that means `Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase()` is returning null. also closing right after you start the asynctask is no good either because the app does not pause until the async task finished, that would defeat the purpose of an asynctask

Comment: @Squonk yes that is the old time the cursor needs to be open but if he is just pulling data then you need to close it. It was never explicidly said so I assumed it was just pulling data